# Is there an equivalent of <$> that I put at the end of an expression, instead of the beginning?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, given a monad `m` and variables with the following types:

```hs
for :: m a
bar :: a -> m b
baz :: b -> c
```

I can combine them into an expression that evaluates to `m c` thus:

```hs
result :: m c
result = baz <$> (foo >>= bar)
```

Is there an expression that will let me re-order this expression and put `baz` last? In other words, is there an operator I can replace `???` with in this expression?

```hs
result2 :: m c
result2 = foo >>= bar ??? baz
```

Comment: you can `fmap` at the end of the chain, so `foo >>= fmap baz . bar`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could compose that with `return`, and then add it to your `>>=` chain:

```
result2 :: m c
result2 = foo >>= bar >>= return . baz
```

Alternatively, exploiting `Data.Functor`, which defines `(<&>) = flip (<$>)`:

```
result2 :: m c
result2 = foo >>= bar <&> baz
```

Comment: I would add that `(<&>)` is [the first result when Hoogling for the desired type signature](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=m+a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+m+b&scope=set%3Astackage).

Comment: It turns out when I do `foo >>= bar >>= return . baz`, hlint suggests changing it to `baz <$> foo >>= bar`, which I don't really like - so that's probably how I ended up here (and then promptly forgot it). `<&>` works very well, though - thank you!